# Conditional to compare two dates, one is x amount of time into the future

Tags: php

Consider:

```
$created_dt = created_dt->created_dt  // string(19) "2013-06-06 15:50:08"
```

I am trying to determine if the current date/time is greater than 24 hours from this time:

```
$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now());

if($current_time > $created_dt + 24 hours){
  //do some things
  }
```

How can this be achieved? Are you able to use <, =,> operators with date strings?

I have tried:

```
$created_dt = mktime(date('H')+1); //Seems to add 6 hours to current time

$created_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now('H'+1)); // Gives me the time and date for now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the date of tomorrow (24h after now) you simply need to add 1 day

```
$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+ 1 Day'));
```

You can actually compare date string with logical operators such as `>` `<` `=`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$current_time = time(); // now (seconds since UNIX epoch)
$test_time = strtotime("2013-06-06 15:50:08"); // same format

if($test_time > $current_time + (24 * 60 * 60)) // 24*60*60 = 24 hours in seconds
    echo 'Greater than 24 hours after now';
else
    echo 'Less than or equal to 24 hours from now';
```